# Получить кнопку,на которой находится курсор

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.
Несколько кнопок размещены на TableLayoutPanel.
Необходимо при наведении мыши на кнопку выводить в лейбле(расположенном ниже) её Tag.
Не понял, как использовать `GetChildAtPoint`, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно вот так: private void button1_MouseEnter( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            string send = ( ( Button ) sender ).Tag.ToString();
            string loc = ( ( Button ) sender ).Location.ToString();
            label1.Text = send+loc;
        }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем использовать `GetChildAtPoint`, если есть событие `MouseEnter`? Можно задать для любого количества кнопок один и тот же обработчик (в коде или в дизайнере), примерно такого вида:

```
private void TableLayoutPanelButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tag = ((Button)sender).Tag;
    // делаем что нужно
}
```